# Is it possible to have a macro function as a QMetaMethod tag?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qmetaobject

[Qt allows you to have arbitrary tags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#tag) on slots/Q_INVOKABLE methods using this syntax:

```
// In the class MainWindow declaration
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
// define the tag text as empty, so the compiler doesn't see it
#  define MY_CUSTOM_TAG
#endif
...
private slots:
    MY_CUSTOM_TAG void testFunc();
```

I want to make a tag that's a macro function, like this:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#  define MY_CUSTOM_TAG(...)
#endif
...
private slots:
    MY_CUSTOM_TAG(someData) void testFunc();
```

Which I hoped would end up as a string in `tag()` like `MY_CUSTOM_TAG(someData)` which my code would parse - however, MOC gives me this error:

```
error: Parse error at ")"
```

Is there a way to make this work? Or does MOC only support simple macros for tags?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified it was during the MOC step. I feared as much the answer would be no, but figured I'd see if anyone figured out a workaround or a different way to do what I'm trying to do

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's wrong with `MY_CUSTOM_TAG_somedata_suitably_encoded`? Tag is just a C string after all.

Comment: I am using the metaobject system to expose various functions to a scripting engine. I've got an `EXPORT` macro so only certain slots are exposed, and was looking to see if it were possible to make an `EXPORT_RENAME(name)` macro to be able to use a different name for the function in the scripting engine. @walkingTarget helped me figure out a way to at least have it be like `MY_CUSTOM_TAG_somedata_suitably_encode` by having an `else` case in the define which I didn't think of, so that is very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tl;dr is that you can do this, but *moc* is picky about what it accepts.

According to the doc you linked, *moc* in Qt 5.0+ will expand preprocessor macros.  You can confirm this through the following example:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
    #define MY_TAG(...)
#else
    #define MY_TAG(x) x
#endif

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    MY_TAG(qt) void test();
};
```

If you inspect the *moc*-generated `moc_test.cpp`, you should find 'qt' within the generated string table.

```
static const qt_meta_stringdata_Test_t qt_meta_stringdata_Test = {
    {
QT_MOC_LITERAL(0, 0, 4), // "Test"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(1, 5, 4), // "test"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(2, 10, 2) // "qt"

    },
    "Test\0test\0qt"
};
```

You can also test for success using QMetaMethod::tag() as described in the linked documentation.

I tested several other macros, and found *moc* to be rigid in what its accepts.  For instance, macros with multiple arguments, and macro bodies including parentheses or dashes resulted in error. *moc* uses its own preprocessor implementation, and it may be limited compared to the GNU C preprocessor.

Comment: Nice. The resulting tag string seems to have to be a whitespace separated list of valid symbol names. So no numbers (without underscore/letter prefix), no operators, and whitespace within parenthesis is reduced to single spaces in resulting tag. But, nested macros work, meaning for example `MY_TAG(another_macro)` will expand `another_macro` (which must still expand to valid symbol names only), and put that in the tag string.

Comment: Thank you, this lets me type in arbitrary strings as a tag without needing to define a new macro every time so this is definitely a good solution!